# Can I convert a WPF page path to a class name

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have an application which pulls XAML page paths from a database. I can then use a navigationservice to navigate to the relevant page when need be. However, I have run into a scenario where I would like to instantiate the page with a specific constructor before navigating to that page.

Is it possible to take a string value such as "\Pages\MyPage.xaml" at runtime and create an object MyPage? Obviously, I could do this with a switch statement on the page path, but I would like it to be a whole lot more dynamic than that.

If anyone has any ideas, or has a better way of doing what I'm trying to do, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string to take off the extension and subdirectory, then take a look at [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)